# Why does writeInt(int v) show as symbols in file but writeBytes(String s) shows properly in the file?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand why is it that when I use this code (using `writeInt(int v)`) I get symbols in the file created.

```
public class Write {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          //create FileOutputStream object
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("v.txt");
          DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
          int str = 2323;
          dos.writeInt(str);
          dos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException : " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

but when I use `writeBytes(String s)` or `writeUTF(String s)` I get the correct string written in the file. I have read that `writeBytes` converts the primitive data `byte` to a sequence of bytes so why don't I get the symbols which I was getting using the previous code using this method?

```
public class Write {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          //create FileOutputStream object
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("v.txt");
          DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
          String str = "hello";
          dos.writeBytes(str);
          dos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException : " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have read that `writeBytes` neglects the 8 high-order bits of each character, but I don't see any difference in the string I entered and in the file so can anyone explain what does it mean by neglecting the 8 bits?

Comment: What character do you think integer 2323 is?

Comment: I am sorry but I am relatively new to programming , I can't understand your question.

Comment: You're writing a 32 bit integer to a file, the integer is 2323. If you look at that file as text you'll get whatever character 0x913 is in whatever character system you're using to view the file.

Comment: @vibhukapoor can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31069333/edit) your question to provide us the output in you `v.txt` file after writing the data?

Comment: The integer 2323 is supposed to appear as ascii codes 0, 0, 9, 19 (NUL NUL HT DC3) in that or another order. The thing that it is supposed to do is to use the binary representation of the number and output these in 8 bits chunks. You're NOT supposed to see the string 2323 in the output. Think of it how should it be able to show a number as 12345 in the 4 bytes output the method is documented to output?

Comment: @moffeltje I am sorry I cant upload snapshot of the document because of low reputation .I only get 1 weird looking symbol as output

Comment: @vibhukapoor If you try to print 1094861636 instead? Do you get wierd symbols?

Comment: @moffeltje no i get ABCD why is that? can you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is as expected. The number 1094861636 happens to be 41424344 in hexadecimal and the ascii codes for A, B, C and D happens to be 41, 42, 43, 44 in hexadecimal.

What `writeInt` does is to break down the number into binary format and output the bytes (8 binary "digits" chunks). Hexadecimal is nifty because each hexadecimal "digit" happens to correspond to four binary "digits".

What you probably want to do is use `writeStr(Integer.toString(yourNumber))` instead. `Integer.toString` converts an integer to its human readable form, while `writeInt` produces something that is more computer readable.